# Image of a Hausdorff Space with certain conditions is closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and let $f:X \to X$  be a continuous map such that $f  \circ f=f$. Prove that $f(X)$ is closed in $X$.

I am showing its complement is open. I had chosen $x \in X \setminus f(X) $ thus $ x \neq f(x).$ then I tried to use Hausdorff Property, but I am unable to show that $ x$ is an interior point of $X \setminus f(X) $

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868536/x-be-a-hausdorff-topological-space-let-fx-to-x-be-a-continuous-map-such).

Comment: @DavidMitra thank you